# temporarily sticky parallax

Tags: css, parallax

On this page, http://www.espn.com/espn/feature/story/_/id/12748163/floyd-mayweather-prepares-2-fight-seal-legacy, if you scroll a while you will get to [an image](http://a.espncdn.com/photo/2015/0424/mag_floyd_mayweather04_laham_js_1600x900.jpg) (a fixed background ) which does not respond to your scrolling action for a second or so... I call this temporarily stick parallax effect but this is my way of referring to this difficult to describe effect.

Does anyone know what it is that makes this *temporarily freezing the image* like that? I think it is a fantastic effect.

None of the parallax tutorial sites I checked do this kind of a demo.

Comment: No idea what you mean by “does not react for a second or so”, as I don’t see it moving _at all_ (in Chrome) - this looks just like a fixed background image to me.

Comment: Yes it is not moving at all for chrome but as you continue to scroll, ( about a second later ) the bottom div comes up and overtakes the image... In a typical parallax, the image is *instantly* over taken by the following div, creating the parrallax efffect. What tricks me is that as you scroll down to that section, you do notice that your scrolling won't work for a second or so while you are on that image ( cause at that moment as you say image is fixed), but if you continue the scroll action, 1 second later, the bottom div comes into play... Not sure if this time, I was able to express it.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is achieved quite easily:
If you inspect the picture elements, you will find that this is just a fixed background-image:

```
#section-1 .section-photo-break.chapter01 {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center 44px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

However, this effect doesn't work on i(e)OS this way^^